# Should I mention that I'm negotiating with another company?

Tags: hiring-process, new-job, cover-letter

I'm in the final hiring process of a company based in UK, and today a company from my country contacted me showing interest on my profile for new open vacancies they have here.

I would prefer to work at this company, first because it's at home and second because it's more related with my professional career. The director of the company told me that send my CV if I am interested, indeed I am.  So I am in the process of creating my cover letter to send to them.

Am I likely to see an advantage or disadvantage if I mention the offer from the first company?  Is it more likely to persuade them to make an offer, or to increase the pace at which they pursue making an offer?

Comment: What is the job experience level?  If it is for something entry-level, the second company might simply move on if they found another company was already processing you.

Comment: @kmd97: It depends. In my case, the other company considered me more seriously once I shared that I was negotiating an offer with another company.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mention it.  A company is not going to say "well, this guy already has a job, let's find someone who has a hard time getting employment" - the benefits of hiring a go-getter with marketable skills outweighs the risk of spending time interviewing someone and then not being able to hire the person - almost every time.

About the only caveat I can come up with is - if this job is so much more attractive that you would be willing to turn down the other offer and wait *for 3 months* for this company to make a hiring decision on you - then don't bother mentioning it, because the other job is really not a factor in your job acceptance process.

Reasons for telling the potential company that another offer is in the works:

1. Being in demand is attractive.
2. To give them a timeline - the more accurate you can be, the better.
3. To make it clear that you are not a guaranteed placement - if they drag their feet, if they fail to communicate in a timely manner, they may lose you.

Comment: 100% true to the point. @yzT what prevents you from marking this answer as the best

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mention it if they don't ask. If you don't have a job, they should assume you have other possibilities.

The key is to not sound like you're trying to use this as leverage. Make sure you understand the time-line for filling the position. If it is too far out or they can't give you an answer, you may want to mention the other offer. I don't see a right or wrong answer since each company and hiring manager is different. You'll have to go with your gut.